# ember.js list template keeps getting bigger on each visit

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

**Summary**

I have a problem with a list displayed by Ember which keeps displaying extra rows each time it is visited. The extra rows are duplicates of those which were initially displayed.

**Detail**

In an Emberjs 2.13.0 app I have a model that looks like this :

import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    cceIdentifierParent: DS.attr('string'),
    cchCceIdParent: DS.attr('string'),
    nodeType: DS.attr('number')
});
```

I have a route, 'diagcctreetoplevelonly', which looks like this :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('diagcctreetoplevelonly');
  }
});
```

And a template that looks like this :

```
{{diag-warningbanner}}
{{#if model.length}}
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
            cceIdentifierParent
        </th>
        <th>
            cchCceIdParent
        </th>
        <th>
            nodeType          
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each model as |treenode|}}
           <tr>
              <td>
                {{treenode.cceIdentifierParent}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{treenode.cchCceIdParent}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{treenode.nodeType}}
              </td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{{else}}
  <p id="blankslate">
    No Tree Nodes found
  </p>
{{/if}}
{{outlet}}
```

That works fine the first time that 'diagcctreetoplevelonly' is visited - 12 rows are rendered - but on subsequent visits (without the underlying data having changed) the table rendered by the template has 12 extra rows for each time it has been visited.

Can anyone explain what i'm doing wrong ? Thank you.

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to the input from @Jeff and @Subtletree I was able to resolve this.

The problem was that the data returned had no 'id' attribute and when I created one the problem went away.

Because of the peculiar nature of the data it didn't actually matter what the id was and I didn't want to make changes to the backend so I created an id dynamically once the data had arrived on the client by creating a model level serializer and overriding the `extractId` method like this :

```
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
    extractId(modelClass, resourceHash) {
        var arrId = [];
        arrId.push(resourceHash['attributes']['cceIdentifierParent']);
        arrId.push(resourceHash['attributes']['cchCceIdParent']);
        arrId.push(resourceHash['attributes']['nodeType']);
        var id = arrId.join('|');
        return id == null || id === '' ? null : id+'';
  },
});
```

It wouldn't have worked in all (perhaps most ?) situations but for my case this was good enough and resolved the problem.

To provide credit where it's due I got the idea for how to do this from the answer by @Casey here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35738573/364088 .

Comment: This looks absolutely right, so I'm guessing a few possibilites: Are the 'extra' datasets identical to the first 12? Does the api payload include proper ids? Is Ember requesting the data on each visit and what does the payload look like?

Comment: Are the extra rows gone when you do a complete refresh?

Comment: @Jeff thanks for your comments, they were part of what allowed me to resolve the issue. I'm about to edit the question to provide more information for any subsequent readers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ember-data` receives records from a server it tries to match them to records already in the store by their id. If no id's are present then it can't find a match so instead of updating them it will just add them.

You could add an id to each record or could fetch the data with ajax and not use `ember-data` for this model.